# Is it possible to hook Chrome DOM Breakpoint events manually in the console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Currently, you can right-click a DOM element from the element-inspector window, and select "break on subtree modifications".  Breakpointing is useful, but I'd like to gather some real-time statistics as well, and was hoping to hook the event from withing the JS console, i.e. fire my callback function instead of actually breaking execution.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the event as follows:

```
// DOMNodeInserted may be more interesting
document.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target);  // Logs the element
});
```

The logged element is "live", so it will not show the element at the time of logging. For the `DOMNodeInserted` event, it may be useful to use: `console.log(event.target.outerHTML);`

Comment: You are my hero, thank you.  I don't suppose you know how to track when a reflow is triggered? :)

Comment: in response to my own comment, I realized I had missed the "timeline" feature on Chrome which shows layout/paint events.